# Invalid FK and PK reference

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, reference, primary-key

Unable to create table as oracle shows ' no matching unique or primary key for this column-list' when I did label the primary key reference for the required table.

First table created successfully:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
  (
    TESTno VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL,
    ExamNo VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL,
    TEST_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    ACTUAL DATE,
    PREDICTED Date,
    CONSTRAINT TESTPKs PRIMARY KEY (TEST_Date, TESTno, ExamNo),
    CONSTRAINT TTESTNO_Fk FOREIGN KEY (TESTno) REFERENCES TESTPAPER (Flightno)
    CONSTRAINT TEXAMNo_FK FOREIGN KEY (ExamNo) REFERENCES Exam (ExamNo)
  );
```

Here's the table i want to create and gives me error:

```
CREATE TABLE Assignment
  (
    TEST_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    ExamNo VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL,
    TestNo VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL,
    Type  VARCHAR2(20),
    Hours_Spent Decimal(4,2),
    CONSTRAINT ASSIGNPKS PRIMARY KEY (TEST_Date, TestNo , ExamNo),
    CONSTRAINT ASSIGNTESTDATE_FK FOREIGN KEY (TEST_Date) REFERENCES TEST(TEST_Date) ON
  DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT ASSIGNTESTNO_FK FOREIGN KEY (TESTno) REFERENCES TESTPAPER (Flightno)
    CONSTRAINT TEXAMNo_FK FOREIGN KEY (ExamNo) REFERENCES Exam (ExamNo)
  );
```

May i know where's the issue that it keeps giving me no matching unique primary keys? I already tried to recreate and labelled the 'test_Date' as my primary key. But oracle can't seems to find.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PK you refer to is `PRIMARY KEY (TEST_Date, TESTno, ExamNo)` — hence the foreign key should be `FOREIGN KEY (TEST_Date, TESTno, ExamNo)` as well. The error you're getting is due to your attempt to refer to a part of `TEST`'s PK.

See also http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c22integ.htm

Comment: +1 exactly right - if the PK is a compound index (multiple columns), then **every FK** referencing it **must** also contain **all** those columns

Comment: but i would like to have my (TEST_Date, TestNo , ExamNo) as my PK and FK but referencing from different tables. Is it possible?

Comment: The only way to do that is to create a unique key on each component of the PK you wish to reference in a foreign key constraint on another table.

Comment: Ok i got it. Manage to create an unique index for my table and alter the constraint. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check the tables you are referencing in your foreign keys.  Those columns must be the primary key or otherwise unique on the foreign table.

Comment: Yes, as you can see that my table test 'test_Date' was defined as primary key already. and in my assignment table, i did references to it and labelled it as primary key. But the error still occur.

Comment: I don't see the other tables, but the primary key on TEST is (TEST_Date, TESTno, ExamNo) and you are only using (TEST_Date) in the foreign key.  There may be an issue with the other tables as well, which is why I gave a generic response to check that the foreign key columns must match the primary key or a unique index on the foreign table.  Sorry if the response was too terse.